# Apache ModRewrite regular expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
/gestion/aa/       => /gestion/aa.php
/gestion/bb/       => /gestion/bb.php
/gestion/a/b/      => /gestion/a/b.php
/gestion/a/b/c/    => /gestion/a/b/c.php
```

---

```
/cmd/aa/           => /cmd/aa.php
/cmd/bb/           => /cmd/bb.php
/cmd/a/b/          => /cmd/a/b.php
/cmd/a/b/c/        => /cmd/a/b/c.php
```

---

```
/json/aa/          => /json/aa.php
/json/bb/          => /json/bb.php
/json/a/b/         => /json/a/b.php
/json/a/b/c/       => /json/a/b/c.php
```

This brought me to this simple regular expression:

```
^/(gestion|cmd|json)/(([^/]+/)*)$ /$1/$2.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem is that `$2` has **always** the `/` within so the results are:

```
/json/aa/          => /json/aa/.php
/json/bb/          => /json/bb/.php
/json/a/b/         => /json/a/b/.php
/json/a/b/c/       => /json/a/b/c/.php
```

Any idea how to get the right regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^/(gestion|cmd|json)/(.+)/$ /$1/$2.php [QSA,L]` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^(gestion|cmd|json)(/.*)/$ /$1$2.php
```